# Enter and DIsplay Emojis in Text Box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, networking, network-programming, wifi

How can I get a textbox in an HTML page to accept emojis ? Basically, I want to display emojis as the SSID of my WiFi. I tried using emojis as my Wifi display name (SSIS) but it won't accept. 
Its a HUWAEI router and I use 192.168.1.1 to connect to it. After which I get the admin page to change the SSID name which is then broadcast. Using Chrome dev tools I can see CSS, HTML, JS and JQuery scripts. Unfortunately, I have very little knowledge on HTML, JS, JQuery etc.
Can anyone please help ? I am using Chrome (v67.xx). I located the part where the text box is coded :

```
<td><input type="text" class="input_style Arabic_dialupNumber" id="ssid_wifiName" maxlength="32" /></td>
```

Please let me know if additional info is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Raj, without any relevant research and information on what you have tried, we can't help you. Also, look at [`this`](https://medium.com/@bcjordan/emojify-your-wi-fi-c01f4ac0b0ab)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can have a TextField with emoji images. One approach that I know is to use a div with contenteditable enabled and have a custom JS script to parse the user input. Check the snippet below.

```js
document.getElementById("emoji").addEventListener('keyup', function(evt) {
  //wait for user to input semi colon
  if (evt.keyCode == 186) {
    var doc = evt.target;
    var txt = doc.innerText || doc.textContent
    doc.innerHTML = (txt).replace("&amp;", "&");
    // put the cursor to the end of the text
    var sel = window.getSelection()
    var range = document.createRange()
    range.setStart(doc, 1);
    range.collapse(true)
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
  }
});
```

```css
.textarea {
  background: white;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<span>Type &amp;#9786; to get a &#9786; emoji</span>
<div id="emoji" class="textarea" contenteditable="true"></div>
```